# Passing Parameters from HTML/JavaScript Interface to Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I am working on a Jenkins pipeline and trying to pass parameters from a custom HTML/JavaScript code inside `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter` to the pipeline. The goal is to allow users to fill these optional parameters if they wish to by enabling or disabling and read the filled values inside the pipeline.

The HTML interface consists of a checkbox to enable advanced parameters and input fields to specify the values.

I am having problems with accessing these values inside the pipeline. How to access these parameters from the pipeline? Thanks in advance.

My Groovy script inside that parameter,

```
return """
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="enable" name="ENB" onclick="show()">
</div>
<div id="advp" style="display: none;">
    <div>
        <input type="number" id="field1" name="field1" value="1" step="1" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" id="field2" name="field2" value="1" step="1" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" id="field3" name="field3" value="1" step="1" required>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function show() {
        var enabled = document.getElementById("enable");
        var advp = document.getElementById("advp");

        if (enabled.checked) {
            advp.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            advp.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
"""
```

Comment: I believe [this material](https://dev.to/nkatarmal/how-to-render-jenkins-build-parameters-dynamically-4309) might help you.